# Changing line number separator color in VS 2017 Community

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I really like the Zenburn theme. As such, I downloaded [this](https://studiostyl.es/schemes/zenburn-2012) theme from studio styles and imported it as settings. Everything seems to have configured correctly except one thing - the line number separator.

If you look at the link above, you'll see there's no line between the line numbers and the code. Just a nice space. When I installed the theme I get this baby-puke-green line separator that is really off-putting:

[image]

I have installed the color editor plugin but I can't seem to find a way to edit this part of the theme. I really like the overall theme, and everything else seems to work correctly, I just really want this awful color gone (I don't even think it's in the theme!).

How can I change/remove this separator so it looks more like the image on https://studiostyl.es?

Comment: Can you make the heading a question perhaps. Also, the image should not be a link. Just click the image icon while editing and copy/paste an image or browse for one such that the image is inline in the question much like how I answered this question?

Comment: @Eric I apparently need 10 reputation for inline links. May need mod help for that - sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Ah, I've done it for you. It wasn't clear to me whether you wanted to change the line numer or the track changes indicator. Neither are a separator in Visual Studio parlance. And what you call a separator is in fact yellow and more pleasing 'green' than the line numbers lol. Can you improve the wording there?

Comment: To make it crystal clear: the track changes indicator only appears after you change something. That's why it is on your screen but not the theme website. It's yellow by default before you save the file and bright green after you save. It disappears at some point completely, for example if you close and reopen the file - I'm not sure about when precisely.

Comment: @Eric apologies, something came up. Im still new to VS and not totally sure of the language. It makes sense that that is the "changes" indicator - it's unusually aggressive - haha.

Comment: Haha well I know the pain. I've been trying to change that black theme in the screenshot to fit my taste. But the structure isn't clear (it's a tree with colors inheriting from others). Well in summary it really helps to know a few letters of whatever its called you want to change. As a tip for new VS users, try Ctrl+. and Ctrl+Q and you can find about any setting and any part of your code if only you know a few letters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Color Theme Editor for Visual Studio 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.VisualStudio2017ColorThemeEditor) you can just search for **line number** for the leftmost puke green and for **track changes** to change the vertical bar in yellow or green by default which is **Track Changes before save** and **Track Changes after save** respectively and change the foreground and background color that way and save your modifications as a custom theme.

[image]

You don't need any theme editor though. The built-in options dialog has a setting for all of those as well.

[image: Tools Options]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this - indeed that "seperator" only appeared that way on a new file and it is the track changes indicator instead. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!